# Embedding a simple 2D graphics application in a GTK# app

Tags: c#, mono, 2d, gtk#

I'm looking to use Mono and GTK# to create a cross-platform application. I need, however, to fill about half the window with an entirely custom display, which can easily be drawn using only text and 2D primitives. How might I go about doing this? I simply have no idea where to start.

Comment: SkiaSharp : https://blog.xamarin.com/cross-platform-2d-graphics-with-skiasharp/ No Linux at this exact moment though (its planned unless the MSFT merger redirects efforts) https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp

Comment: Unfortunately, Linux is my development platform, so that's not really acceptable. Thank you though, it does look like just what I need.